# Android Studio Rendering Error after project builds

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

Edited

I use E-Clips as my IDE to develop android programs.
im going to migrate to Android Studio , so Im really new to this IDE.

after installing Android Studio , When I try to Create a new project , I Choose API 15 (android 4.0.3) and for Activity Page I choose the Blank Theme .

[image: Creating New Project]

[image: Selecting Blank Theme]

**When project opens and gradle finish its syncing , XML pages on design tab doesn't show anything and There IS no error .**

[image]

and after I change the rendering target to API 15 ,the following message appears :

[image]

[image]

here is what on my xml file and please note that I didn't change the default codes when project created.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="test.apptune.ir.stack.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my biuld.gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.apptune.ir.stack"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    }
```

I would be Thankful if you Help me on this regard.

Comment: add your build.gradle... Some libs you're missing

Answer (score 0):

Pouya Heydari...Add android support design library in build.gradle(Module:app) in Gradle Scripts like that

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

**Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager(Tools->ANdroid->SDk Manager-> Extras-> Android Support Repository).

and then rebuild the project. thanks

Comment: Dear Vishal Chauhan Thanks for your response. I added lines above , and the error changed to this : The following classes could not be instantiated : -android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout. and the exception detail is : Java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Pouya.. I have updated my answer. Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

Change AppTheme parent in res/values/styles.xml to resolve this problem. Replace

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

with

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. Thanks...

Comment: Change the rendering target from API 15 to API 22(or which Android SDK (API version you have install) ), and then build the project......

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, when i set the target to API 22 , the Design tab shows nothing.(no emulator)